# Why is sass-loader broken when implementing react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I'm working in React and using Sass for the CSS. I'm currently trying to use react-router-dom to handle routing, but something is not quite right with it. I have an App that looks like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Router>
      <div className={styles.grad}>
        <div className={styles.centered}>
          <div className={styles.blueBox}>
            <Link to="music">music</Link>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.redBox}>
            <Link to="visuals">visuals</Link>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.greenBox}>
            <Link to="shop">shop</Link>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.purpleBox}>
            <Link to="about">about</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/music">
          <Music />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/visuals">
          <Visuals />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/shop">
          <Shop />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/about">
          <About />
        </Route>
      </Switch>

      </Router>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     render() {
|         return (
>             <div className={styles.footer}>
|                 Footer stuff goes here...
|             </div>
```

and the strangest part is that it compiles fine if I comment out the switch component and everything nested in it. **EDIT:** this error comes from the Footer.tsx file.

I've tried configuring webpack.config.js and reinstalling my sass-loaders.

for reference, all of my components I'm trying to route to just look like this:

```
export class Shop extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Footer />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

just simple components that render a header and footer.

Edit: the code for the footer throwing the error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styles from './styles.module.scss'

export class Footer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.footer}>
                Footer stuff goes here...
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

and the corresponding scss file:

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: -3;
  }
```

Comment: How/where are you importing `styles`?

Comment: For App or the components? both of them just have a line like
import styles from './styles.module.scss'

Comment: Is it a specific route handler component? Have you tried isolating the issue down to a single route? Does the error tell you which file is triggering the error?

Comment: I havent, but they're all identical as far as what's in the components. And the error comes from the Footer.tsx file.

Comment: Can you post the Footer.tsx file in its entirety and the scss it's importing?

Comment: Done in the edit above.

Comment: still don’t see the scss.

Comment: Sorry missed the part where you asked for the scss. I added it.